# Expected value of sum of two larger of three dice

Tags: probability-theory, dice

I've been trying to figure out the expected value of the outcome when you roll three N sided dice and take the sum of the larger two values. Would also like to know the EV for when you take the sum of the smaller two values, though I assume these have symmetry around the die's average value.

I get that I can take the EV of the total average sum, and subtract the EV of the minimum, but calculating the EV of the minimum of 3 is the hard part. I know each single die is a uniform discrete RV, I'm just having trouble turning that concept into a PMF for the minimum of the 3. I guess the PMF that the minimum is k can be written as the probability that all three RVs are less than or equal to k and at least one of the 3 equals k, and got (3N^2 - 3N + 1)/N^3 but when trying to get the EV from that I can an answer that doesn't match simulations for test N values.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that the sum of the two largest is equal to the sum of the three minus the least.

Comment: Hint: Take the expected value of the sum of all three dice (easy) and subtract the expected value of the smallest die. The second part is not trivial, but easier than the original problem.

Comment: For $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,N\},~$ let $~f(k)~$ denote the probability that all three dice are **at least** $~(k).~$  Also, let $~g(k)~$ denote the probability that the smallest die is **exactly** $~(k).~$ Then, $$g(1) = 1 - f(2), ~g(N) = f(N),$$ and $$g(k) = f(k) - f(k+1) ~: 2\leq k \leq (N-1).$$  Then, the expected value of the smallest die is $$\sum_{k=1}^N \left[g(k) \times k\right].$$

Answer (score 1):

Following @ThomasAndrews' comment, denote by $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ the three dice, by $X_{(1)}$, $X_{(2)}$ and $X_{(3)}$ the sorted dice. Then the expectation of the two largest is
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[X_{(2)}+X_{(3)}] &= \mathbb E[X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}+X_{(3)}-X_{(1)}]\\
&= \mathbb E[X_1+X_2+X_3]-\mathbb E[X_{(1)}]\\
&= 3\frac{N+1}{2}-\sum_{k=1}^N \mathbb P[X_{(1)}\geq k]\\
&= 3\frac{N+1}{2}-\sum_{k=1}^N \left(\frac{N-k+1}{N}\right)^3\\
&=3\frac{N+1}{2}-\frac{1}{N^3}\sum_{k=1}^N k^3\\
&=3\frac{N+1}{2}-\frac{1}{N^3}\frac{N^2 (N+1)^2}{4}\\
&= \frac{6 N(N+1)-(N+1)^2}{4N}\\
&=\frac{5 N^2+4N-1}{4N}
\end{align*}

Comment: For the N=2 case, the possible outcomes are:
(1 1 1) 
(1 1 2)
(1 2 1)
(2 1 1)
(2 2 1)
(2 1 2)
(1 2 2)
(2 2 2)

This is 8 cases, 1 where the outcome is 2, 3 where the outcome is 3, and 4 where the outcome is 4. EV = (1(2) + 3(3) + 4(4))/8 = 27/8

With your formula, EV = (20 - 9)/8 = 11/8, which is not consistent assuming my math is right. I think the PMF of the minimum must be more complex than what you have there but I'm not sure how to get it

Comment: Well $\mathbb P[X_{(1)}\geq k] = \mathbb P[X_1\geq k, X_2\geq k,X_3\geq k]=\left( \mathbb P[X_1\geq k] \right)^3=\left( \frac{N-k+1}{N} \right)^3$, so I think this part is fine, I have probably made a mistake somewhere else but the idea is essentially there. Maybe a good way to proceed is for you to ask me about what part is not clear so we can find the mistake together.

Comment: Well I made a mistake in the very last step, fixed ! (just a minus sign for $4N$)